# How to skip overlap intervals in the following query to get the accurate per day track time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query ([see SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b23feb/3/0)) which calculates the total track time per day. It worked fine until I found that my data is not clean and it has some intervals overlapping (i.e. starttime is repeated in some cases).

There are 1440 minutes in a day and therefore the maximum track time should be 1440, but due to the overlapping intervals the track time exceeds 1440 minutes per day in some cases.

At the moment the query makes it 1440 if the sum exceeds 1440. But if a value is less than 1440 it still can be wrong.

**For example**

One interval is from 10:00 to 14:00.

Second interval is from 13:00 to 15:00.

End result is 4 + 2 = 6 hours, where hour between 13:00 and 14:00 is counted twice.

> End result is 360 minutes, which is less than 1440, but it **is not a
>   correct answer**, because data is not correct.

I want some help to fix the query so that it skips overlaps and calculates the correct track time. Thanks

```
;WITH
CTE_Dates
AS
(
    SELECT
        Email
        ,CAST(MIN(StartTime) AS date) AS StartDate
        ,CAST(MAX(EndTime) AS date) AS EndDate
    FROM track
    GROUP BY Email
)
SELECT
    CTE_Dates.Email
    ,DayStart AS xDate
    -- if some intervals overlap, it is possible
    -- to get SUM more than 1440 per day
    -- truncate such values for now
    ,CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, RangeStart, RangeEnd)) / 60, 0) > 1440
    THEN 1440
    ELSE ISNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, RangeStart, RangeEnd)) / 60, 0) 
    END AS TrackMinutes
FROM
    Numbers
    CROSS JOIN CTE_Dates
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(day, Numbers.Number-1, CTE_Dates.StartDate) AS DayStart
            ,DATEADD(day, Numbers.Number, CTE_Dates.StartDate) AS DayEnd
    ) AS A_Date
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            -- MAX(DayStart, StartTime)
            CASE WHEN DayStart > StartTime THEN DayStart ELSE StartTime END AS RangeStart

            -- MIN(DayEnd, EndTime)
            ,CASE WHEN DayEnd < EndTime THEN DayEnd ELSE EndTime END AS RangeEnd
        FROM track AS T
        WHERE
            T.Email = CTE_Dates.Email
            AND T.StartTime < DayEnd
            AND T.EndTime > DayStart
    ) AS A_Track
WHERE
    Numbers.Number <= DATEDIFF(day, CTE_Dates.StartDate, CTE_Dates.EndDate)+1
GROUP BY DayStart, CTE_Dates.Email
ORDER BY DayStart;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by posting your query here rather than linking it outside Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "gaps and islands" problem. I faked my own test data (since you didn't provide any), but I think it works. The key intuition is that all values within the same "island" (that is, contiguous time interval) will have the same difference from a row_number() column. If you want a little insight into it, do a raw select from the `IntervalsByDay` cte (as opposed to the subquery I have now); this will show you the islands calculated (with start and end points).

edit: I didn't see that you had a fiddle on the first go around. My answer has been changed to reflect your data and desired output

```
with i as (
    select datediff(minute, '2013-01-01', StartTime) as s,
        datediff(minute, '2013-01-01', EndTime) as e
    from #track
), brokenDown as (
    select distinct n.Number
    from i
    join dbadmin.dbo.Numbers as n
        on n.Number >= i.s
        and n.Number <= i.e
), brokenDownWithID as (
    select Number, Number - row_number() over(order by Number) as IslandID,
        cast(dateadd(minute, number, '2013-01-01') as date) as d
    from brokenDown
), IntervalsByDay as (
    select
        dateadd(minute, min(number), '2013-01-01') as [IntervalStart],
        dateadd(minute, max(number), '2013-01-01') as [IntervalEnd],
        d,
        max(Number) - min(Number) + 1 as [NumMinutes]
    from brokenDownWithID
    group by IslandID, d
)
select d, sum(NumMinutes) as NumMinutes
from IntervalsByDay
group by d
order by d
```

Comment: Data is provided in the fiddle, click the link in my question.