# How can I join my data to a calendar to get a record for each day from start to end in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the sample data [See the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b82a1/1). I want to generate a calendar from start(column 3) to last date (column 4) for each user and plot the data against it. I want to display 0 for which their is no data. I think I can create a calendar table and then cross it but I am not sure. Can any one please suggest the simplest way to achieve it. I am expecting the following outcome from the solution.

```
╔════╦════════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ userid ║    date    ║ total ║
╠════╬════════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-13 ║   200 ║
║  2 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-14 ║   200 ║
║  3 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-15 ║   200 ║
║  4 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-16 ║     0 ║
║  5 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-17 ║     0 ║
║  6 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-18 ║     0 ║
║  7 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-19 ║   200 ║
║  8 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-20 ║   200 ║
║  9 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-21 ║     0 ║
║ 10 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-22 ║     0 ║
║ 11 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-23 ║   200 ║
║ 12 ║ abc    ║ 2015-01-24 ║   200 ║
║ 13 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-10 ║     0 ║
║ 14 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-11 ║     0 ║
║ 15 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-12 ║   200 ║
║ 16 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-13 ║   200 ║
║ 17 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-14 ║     0 ║
║ 18 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-15 ║   200 ║
║ 19 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-16 ║   200 ║
║ 20 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-17 ║   200 ║
║ 21 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-18 ║   200 ║
║ 22 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-19 ║     0 ║
║ 23 ║ efg    ║ 2015-02-20 ║     0 ║
╚════╩════════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

UPDATE
I generated the date table between the two date using the following query but I dont know how to combine them.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateDates(@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
returns table as
return (
SELECT DATEADD(day,Number-1,@startdate) as thedate
FROM Numbers
WHERE Number <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate) + 1
);
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (number int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO Numbers values (1);
GO
INSERT Numbers SELECT number + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers
GO 20
```

Comment: select from your numbers table and convert Number into a date (try dateadd from start date), left join that date to your data's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45689/2/0)

`CTE_Users` gives us list of all users with Start and End dates for each user.

It is joined with the `Calendar` table to generate row for each date for each user.

Finally it is left joined with the main table `Test` to return `Total` for each date. `ISNULL` ensures that those dates that don't have data return 0.

```
WITH
CTE_Users
AS
(
    SELECT
        Userid
        ,MIN(startdate) AS StartDate
        ,MAX(enddate) AS EndDate
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY Userid
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CTE_Users.Userid, Calendar.dt) AS ID
    ,CTE_Users.Userid
    ,T.Id1
    ,Calendar.dt
    ,ISNULL(T.Total, 0) AS Total
FROM
    CTE_Users
    INNER JOIN Calendar ON
            Calendar.dt >= CTE_Users.StartDate
        AND Calendar.dt <= CTE_Users.EndDate
    LEFT JOIN TEST AS T ON
        T.Userid = CTE_Users.Userid
        AND T.date1 = Calendar.dt
ORDER BY CTE_Users.Userid, Calendar.dt;
```

**Result**

```
| ID | Userid |    Id1 |         dt | Total |
|----|--------|--------|------------|-------|
|  1 |    abc |      1 | 2015-01-13 |   200 |
|  2 |    abc |      2 | 2015-01-14 |   200 |
|  3 |    abc |      3 | 2015-01-15 |   200 |
|  4 |    abc | (null) | 2015-01-16 |     0 |
|  5 |    abc | (null) | 2015-01-17 |     0 |
|  6 |    abc | (null) | 2015-01-18 |     0 |
|  7 |    abc |      4 | 2015-01-19 |   200 |
|  8 |    abc |      5 | 2015-01-20 |   200 |
|  9 |    abc | (null) | 2015-01-21 |     0 |
| 10 |    abc | (null) | 2015-01-22 |     0 |
| 11 |    abc |      6 | 2015-01-23 |   200 |
| 12 |    abc |      7 | 2015-01-24 |   200 |
| 13 |    def | (null) | 2015-02-10 |     0 |
| 14 |    def | (null) | 2015-02-11 |     0 |
| 15 |    def |      8 | 2015-02-12 |   200 |
| 16 |    def |      9 | 2015-02-13 |   200 |
| 17 |    def | (null) | 2015-02-14 |     0 |
| 18 |    def |     10 | 2015-02-15 |   200 |
| 19 |    def |     11 | 2015-02-16 |   200 |
| 20 |    def |     12 | 2015-02-17 |   200 |
| 21 |    def |     13 | 2015-02-18 |   200 |
| 22 |    def | (null) | 2015-02-19 |     0 |
| 23 |    def | (null) | 2015-02-20 |     0 |
```

`ID` is a row number generated on the fly.
`Id1` is original IDs from the `Test` table.

I would generate `Calendar` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Calendar](
    [dt] [date] NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dt] ASC
));

-- 10K dates from 2000-01-01 till 2027-05-18
INSERT INTO Calendar (dt)
SELECT TOP (10000)
    DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1, '2000-01-01') AS dt
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Comment: Many thanks, spot on. I believe this is the simplest it can get.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (and in general, the best way) is to build a "Tally" table of sequential integers (1..N) or in the case of dates, or a specialized "Calendar" table* of sequential dates like you mentioned (from "beginning of desired date range" to "end of desired date range") and then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from that table (which contains all rows of interest) to the table containing your actual data/metrics.

*Note that if you build a generic table of sequential `INT` values (1..N), you can dynamically generate a "Calendar" and other sequential ranges by using `DATEADD` and other similar functions.

**UPDATE, WITH EXAMPLE:**
If you create a table called "Numbers" with one int column named "Number", then your syntax will end up looking something like this:

```
select t1.id, t1.userid, t2.date_value, isnull(t1.total, 0) as total
from (
    select dateadd(day, Number, <Arbitrary_Start_Date>) as date_value
    from Numbers
) t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test t1 on t1.date1 = t2.date_value
order by t2.date_value
```

*Remember of course that for all days not in your "Test" table, this will still result in a row being returned for that (and every) day with a "total" of 0, but other columns will be NULL, as a (desired) result of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I am able to add the table but cant combine them